# IllegalStateException & InvocationTargetException

Tags: android

I have no idea of the crash stack traces. I got the **IllegalStateException** & **InvocationTargetException**. But there is no hint which code generates these error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4710)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22393)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:173)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6459)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method:0)
at   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:938)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:828)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method:0)
at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4705)
```

The above is obtained in Google Play console. No line number is provided. So, I cannot know which line cause the exception

Comment: from which line you are getting this error post your code

Comment: put your java code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your layout `xml` file you have applied `android:onClick="someFunctionName"`, whereas in your activity/fragment there is **not** such a method:

```
public void someFunctionName(View view) {
}
```

Comment: I have too many android:onClick defined in xml (total 57 xml files). Is there any quick method to find them ?

Comment: remove all of them and create them with setOnClickListener?

Comment: Not necessarily. Create appropriate functions in java classes.